# Can not run Xcode 7.0.1 on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, xcode, dmg

I can not run Xcode 7.0.1 on my **MacBook Pro** *(Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013, 4GB of RAM, 128GB SSD, 20+GB of free space, OSX 10.10.5)*. I downloaded the DMG file from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode%20_7.0.1/Xcode_7.0.1.dmg), and can run it on my **Mac mini** *(Late 2012, 16GB of RAM, 1TB HDD, 200+GB of free space, OSX 10.10.5)*, but can not run it on my MacBook. The DMG file seems intact and I can browse the contents of Xcode.app; it is seamlessly copied to `/Applications` folder. There is no error code or whatsoever, except the phrase "The application "Xcode" can't be opened."

Xcode 6.0.1 runs perfectly on my MacBook.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I *tail* ed `/var/system/system.log` as patrix suggested and here's an interesting line:

```
kernel[0]: exec of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MaxOS/Xcode denied since it was quarantined by Microsoft\x20Remote\x20Desktop and created without user consent, qtn-flags was 0x00000006
```

WTH?

Comment: Anything of interest in `/var/log/system.log`? Did you copy the DMG to the MBP and install from there or did you just copy the Xcode.app over from the Mac mini?

Comment: @patrix I copied the DMG to MBP. I will tail `/var/log/system.log` and get back to you

Comment: @patrix Added `system.log` to the question.

Comment: Fascinating, never seen that before. Which quarantine setting do you have (Preferences/Security/General) for app downloads?

Comment: @patrix Mac AppStore and Identified Developers. I tried setting it to anywhere but still can't launch Xcode :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had downloaded Xcode on my Windows Server 2012 R2 and copied it to my MBP using Microsoft Remote Desktop for OSX. Apparently this had lead to the `DMG` file being flagged for `quarantine`. I simply removed the quarantine attribute in `terminal` using `xattr`

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me when I first downloaded Xcode 7 onto my MacBook Pro. My solution was to copy the app onto my external hard drive, delete the copy on my internal drive, run the app on the external drive, then copy it back over to the internal drive. I've never had any problems with Xcode 7 since.